# Avoid cancelling of parent job on exception on child coroutine

Tags: kotlin, kotlinx.coroutines

I'm experimenting with **handling exceptions in Kotlin coroutines on Android**.

My use case is I want to do bunch of tasks on background(in async manner) and update multiple UI components on a single activity.

I've designed a `BaseActivity` structure to implement `CoroutineScope` so I can couple couroutines invoked with the lifecycle of activity.

Also, I've a `Repository` class which handles network calls.

I've achieved running multiple tasks concurrently. I know if I use a single `Job` object to cancel all coroutines on `onDestroy()` of the activity and doing (`launch`) multiple coroutines in activity, Exception in any single coroutine will cancel the `Job` from its `CoroutineContext`. And since `Job` is attached to lifecycle of activity, it will cancel all other coroutines too.

I've tried using a **`CoroutineExceptionHandler`**. It catches exception but cancels the `Job` too. Which in result cancels all other coroutines.

What I want?

1. Be able to use **single** `Job` object to attach with activity lifecycle
2. Exception in one coroutine **shouldn't** cancel other coroutines

Adding code below

```
class BaseActivity : AppCompatActivity(), CoroutineScope {

val job = Job()
override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
    get() = Dispatchers.Main + job

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    launch(coroutineContext) {
        Log.i("GURU", "launch1 -> start")
        val result1Deferred = async { Repository().getData(1) }
        val result2Deferred = async { Repository().getData(2) }

        Log.i("GURU", "awaited result1 = " + result1Deferred.await() + result2Deferred.await())
    }

//If Exception is Thrown, Launch1 should still continue to complete
    advancedLaunch(coroutineContext) {
        Log.i("GURU", "launch2 -> start")
        val result1Deferred = async { Repository().getData(3) }

        val result2Deferred = async { Repository().getData(4) }

        delay(200)
        throw Exception("Exception from launch 2")


        Log.i("GURU", "awaited result2 = " + result1Deferred.await() + result2Deferred.await())
    }


}



fun CoroutineScope.advancedLaunch(context: CoroutineContext = EmptyCoroutineContext,
                                  exceptionBlock: (Throwable) -> Unit = {Log.i("GURU", it.message)},
                                  launchBlock: suspend CoroutineScope.() -> Unit) {
    val exceptionHandler = CoroutineExceptionHandler { _, throwable -> exceptionBlock(throwable)}
    launch(context + exceptionHandler) { launchBlock() }
}

override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    job.cancel()
    Log.i("GURU", "job -> cancelled")
}
}
```

The Log Result of this is

```
I/GURU: launch1 -> start
I/GURU: launch2 -> start
I/GURU: getData -> start 1
I/GURU: getData -> start 2
I/GURU: getData -> start 4
I/GURU: getData -> start 3
I/GURU: Exception from launch 2

    --------- beginning of crash
```

Comment: You might want to replace your `Job` with [`SupervisorJob`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/exception-handling.html#supervision).

Comment: @Pawel Thanks. I missed it in docs. Add this in a proper answer and I'll accept

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You might want to replace your `Job` with [`SupervisorJob`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/exception-handling.html#supervision).

It prevents exceptions from propagating "upwards" (one failed child will not cause entire job to fail), but still allows you to push cancellation "downwards" (to running children).